# How to get Django to put tables in different schema

Tags: django, django-models, postgis, database-backups, geodjango

I have a GeoDjango (Django 1.5) application running with PostGIS 2.  Traditionally, when backing up a PostgreSQL database without PostGIS, I would use pg_dump.  The PostGIS documentation recommends to use pg_dump as well, but to also put all of the tables to be backed up in a separate (non-public) schema.  Then, when taking a backup, just backup the tables in the non-public schema, so that all of the PostGIS objects are not backed up as well.

The problem that I am encountering is how to get Django to put tables in a separate schema.  I have seen different suggestions on the various forums, but none that specifically addresses GeoDjango.

Comment: Have you tried using django's manage.py dumpdata command to dump your data into JSON?

Comment: Yes, both this, and the django smuggler application seem to take a database backup with GeoDjango.  I was hoping for something more at the database level.  I have a large database, and dumping all of that spatial data into Json takes a bit longer than a traditional database backup would.

Comment: Of course you realize that using pg_dump gives you no point in time recovery, right? If you need that you'll need to turn on wal archiving and use pg_basebackup (for >= version 9.1). Docs are here: [Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/continuous-archiving.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually control which schema(s) Django's using with the connection_created signal.  Something like this works in both manage.py and wsgi.py (this is straight from my wsgi.py).

```py
DONE = []
def set_schema(sender, **kwargs):
    if DONE:
        return
    DONE[:] = [1]
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("set search_path to my_schema, public;")
    DONE[:] = []

from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
connection_created.connect(set_schema)
```

The `DONE` ugliness is to prevent recursion, and wasn't needed before Django 1.4 or 1.5.

Django will find tables in any of the schemas you list, but only create them in the first on your list.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/signals/#connection-created

Comment: So, in your example all of the tables will be created in the schema: my_schema?

Comment: @SagebrushGIS - yes, any tables you create will be in my_schema, both schemas will be searched for tables